# Get files from other ftp server into meteor app

Tags: meteor, ftp

I need to find a way to read files from a remote ftp server:

```
ftp.server.com/path/to/folder
```

Inside the folder are text files which contain csv data. The data then has to go into the meteor's MongoDB. I can kind of see that it is a problem to do this from the client, because client javascript does not speak FTP. What about the meteor server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an npm module to do this on the meteor server.

Add the [meteorhacks:npm package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) in. Add the file to the generated `packages.json` file.

A suggested package would be the `https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp` package.

Server side code:

```
var Client = Meteor.npmRequire("ftp");

var c = new Client();
c.on('ready', function() {
  c.list(function(err, list) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.dir(list);
    c.end();
  });
});
// connect to localhost:21 as anonymous
c.connect();
```